# Does precedence make < to be executed before ==?

Tags: c

For following code:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    c = 5;
    d = 5;
    a = 10;
    b = 8;
    if (a == c++ && b < d++);
    printf("c=%d d=%d\n", c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `c=6 d=5`

I know since the first expression in the if statement evaluates to false, the second expression is not evaluated and hence the output. However, I read the following words in ANSI C by Balaguruswamy:

> Since the operator `<` enjoys a higher priority compared to `==`,  `b < d++`
>   is evaluated first and then `a == c++`.

Now according to this, shouldn't the value of `d` become `6` and not `c`?

Comment: Order of evaluation of subexpressions is independent of both associativity and precedence. Associativity and precedence determine in what order the operators are executed but do not determine in what order the subexpressions are evaluated. Operators `&&`, `||` `,` like introduces a sequence point. And in the case of &&, || operator evaluation happens from left-to-right and complete expression evaluates accorting to Short-circuit logic

Comment: Is this code also in the book, related to the text you're quoting ? The quote says nothing about there being an `&&` operator too - which is quite important in this piece of code.

Comment: It has the same code with &&. The book is wrong. I was just comfirming. I wish we had an unambiguous book for C. Half of my time is wasted in correcting the books!

Comment: If you're a moderately experienced programmer and just need to know how C differs from other languages, I'd suggest going straight to [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). It's somewhat dated, since there are places where ANSI C has evolved since then, but it was written by experts for experts.

Comment: @user3152736: Here is [a draft of the C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). It is essentially authoritative. It has fewer errors and is less ambiguous than textbooks. However, it is not without flaw or shortcoming. And you may find it harder to read at first.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has worked on standards: They're certainly the Ultimate Answer to the Ultimate Question of Code, the Universe and Everything. But they're written to be read by folks implementing the standard rather than folks using it -- "prescriptive rather than descriptive" -- which means the info is all there but not always in the place a beginner would think to look for it. Great reference, less good tutorial. Alas, I haven't seen a really good book on modern C either.

Answer (score 4):

NO. If the book is quoted that for this specific problem then the book is wrong (my advice is to get better one: I would suggest [C primer plus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326965)). Logical `&&` and `||` operator always evaluates left to right. In this case `b < d++` is not evaluated as `a == c++` is `false` (because of the short circuit behavior of the logical `&&` operator). `d` is not incremented at all, it is still equal to `5`.

Comment: So the statement in the book is not correct, right? Even if < does enjoy a higher priority than ==, in such a case it is not evaluated first, right?

Comment: @EricPostpischil; `"Since the operator < enjoys a higher priority compared to ==,b< d++ is evaluated first and then a==c++."`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; I thought it is quoted for this specific question. Sorry for that. I edited my answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; [Book is wrong!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606372/does-precedence-make-to-be-executed-before/21606423?noredirect=1#comment32644783_21606372). :)

Answer (score 4):

The text of the book is wrong, assuming you have quoted it correctly in context.

In `a == c++ && b < d++`, the expression is grouped as `(a == c++) && (b < d++)` due to grammar rules. However, the precedence by which things are grouped does not fully determine the order in which they are evaluated.<sup>1</sup>

Precedence is a compile-time property that tells us how expressions are structured. Evaluation is a run-time behavior that tells us how expressions are computed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Precedence partially determines evaluation order because the operands of an operator must be evaluated before the operator is. E.g., in `(a*b)+(c-d)`, `a*b` and `c-d` must be evaluated before the `+` can be evaluated. This is not by any rule of grammar or precedence or association but simply because it is impossible to figure out the value of `+` until you know the values of its operands. But note that precedence does not tell us which of `a*b` and `c-d` is evaluated first, even though `*` has higher precedence than `-`.

Comment: I like your answer, but I disagree with this line *`the precedence by which things are grouped does not determine the order in which they are evaluated`* -- in a *grouped* evaluated then precedence matters.  'Precedence' is to impose order of evaluation. Precedence rules fails when different kinds of operators appears in an expression e.g. in OP's code maths and logical operator appears in same expression -- What I means precedence can effect order of evaluation.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I updated the answer to change it to precedence does not “fully determine” the order.

Answer (score 2):

`false && anything` is always `false`, so when the left hand is already `false` it's redundant to check the right side. That's why only `a` gets incremented and `d` stays with the initial value.

---

Edit: The book is wrong.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun: The question is not asking about how `&&` is evaluated. It is asking about the text of the book that appears to contradict this. The answer is that the book is wrong (if it has been quoted correctly in context).

Answer (score 2):

> Since the operator < enjoys a higher priority compared to ==,b< d++ is evaluated first and then a==c++.

But as these operators are not used adjacent to each other, their relative priority doesn't matter.

`a == c++` is evaluated first, and only if it evaluates to `true` (i.e. `!= 0`) will the `b < d++` expression be evaluated.

Comment: Can you please give me an example in which these operators are adjacent to each other? I'd give my life for it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is that d++ is not executed. It's called logical operator short circuit -> basically the right expression is never executed.

Check out [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) for more info.

Comment: The question is not about that. It is about the text in the book that contradicts the fact that `d++` is not executed.

Comment: even though the wording does not ask it specifically; I feel that  the problem is why d++ is not executed as intuition would dictate...Hence my answer

Answer (score -3):

`<` is executed before `==`

[Precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Comment: But that doesn't matter in this expression.

Comment: `<` is not always executed before `==`. For example, in `0 == 0 && 1 < 2`, `0 == 0` is evaluated first, then `1 < 2` is evaluated.